# Unable to make an HTTP request

Tags: django, python-3.x

## Context

I'm trying to save a link to an image in my app. I enforced the "url" format by using a `URLField` in the DB model but I wanted to go further and validate that the given link really targets an image.

To do that, I make a HEAD request to the given url and I check if "image" is contained in the `Content-Type` header of the response.

## Issue

This works well on my computer but when I upload it to prod it doesn't work anymore.

In prod I'm running python 3.5 on Docker ([`python:3.5` Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/6ebbaa8a56cdf4021c78e87b3872be3861ac072a/3.5/jessie/Dockerfile)), I tried to run it the same way on my computer but I wasn't able to reproduce the bug. The container runs on a VM on a dedicated server at OVH. I'm one of the admins of the server, but I don't control the whole network infrastructure. I'm adding this info in the post.

When running the incriminated line, the app hangs then crashes and restarts, resulting in a 502 from nginx which is used as a frontend. Here are the logs at the time of the crash :

```
[11] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14)
[14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
[20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
```

## What I tried

### Code

I tried to do this check in a validator function added to the `validators` list in the DB model, and I also tried to create a custom form field overriding the `clean` method.

Both methods run smoothly but fail if they have to run this line :

```
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

I also tried with the `requests` module, same behavior with this line :

```
res = requests.head(url)
```

I also tried to add a `requests.head` call in the `dispatch` method of a view class and I had the same behavior.

#### Minimal (non-)working example

Here's a minimal code sample with requests as it's much more readable and short :

File `validators.py`

```
def validate_image_url(url):
    res = requests.head(url)
    if 'image' not in res.headers.get('Content-Type'):
        raise ValidationError('Not an image')
```

File `models.py`

```
class Test:
    logo_url = URLField("Logo url", blank=True, validators=[validate_image_url])
```

### CLI

I tried to run a python shell inside the prod container and run the requests, I had no issue. I also tried a `manage.py shell`, no issue either.

Do you guys have any idea ? I'm feeling lost here. Current assumptions are :

- Container blocks HTTP requests (unlikely because python shell inside container has no issue)
- Container blocks HTTP requests from main process

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your docker container is not allowed to make HTTP(s) requests. This is a common security pattern when you configure a server.
A timeout usually indicates that there was a packet filter in between that said **drop**.

How to tackle this issue depends on who is administrator of the network infrastructure and what is offered.

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't think about it. I tried to run a python shell inside the prod container and run the requests, I had no issue. The container runs on a VM on a dedicated server at OVH. I'm one of the admins of the server, but I don't control the whole network infrastructure. I'm adding this info in the post.

Comment: I still bet on an issue with the container. Code that runs locally and breaks in production has its problem nearly always in the server configuration and/or installed library version. Do you also run the container locally in development?

Comment: I agree with you on an issue with the container. When I said I tested locally I meant in a container indeed, but they don't have the exact same configuration. Do you know how I could copy a config from prod to local ?

Comment: You should test this inside the productive environment. When you told that you ran a python shell in the prod container. Was this the prod container running locally or the prod container running at OVH?

Comment: It was the prod container running at OVH.

Comment: Couln't it be the container preventing its main process from making HTTP requests ? I don't know if this kind of security measure exist.

Comment: I also tried to add a `requests.head` call in the `dispatch` method of a view class and I had the same behavior. Added this to the question.

Comment: There is selinux that is capable of doing such things - which distro do you use?

Comment: I'm using `python:3.5` as my base image. Here is the link to the Dockerfile they use : https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/6ebbaa8a56cdf4021c78e87b3872be3861ac072a/3.5/jessie/Dockerfile